# fromEnum toEnum Instance?

Tags: haskell

```
data Suit = Spade | Heart | Club | Diamond deriving (Eq, Ord, Enum, Show)

data Pip = Ace | Two | Three | Four | Five | Six | Seven | Eight | Nine    | Ten | Jack | Queen | King deriving (Eq, Ord, Enum, Show)

data Card = Card
       {suit :: Suit
       ,pip :: Pip
       } deriving (Eq,Ord, Show)

type Deck = [Card]

data EOBoard = EOBoard
         {foundations :: [Deck]
         ,columns     :: [Deck]
         ,reserve    :: [Deck]
         } deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

instance Enum Card where
```

This is a solitaire data structure 
How can I make `Card` enumerable, with `Enum` instances from 
`Card{suit = Spade, pip = Ace}`, `Card{suit = Spade, pip = Two}` .. `Card{suit = Heart, pip = Ace}`.. `Card{suit = Club, pip = Ace}` .. `Card{suit = Diamond, pip = Ace} ..Card{suit = Diamond, pip = King}`.

Comment: hint use `(fromEnum $ maxBound Ace)*(fromEnum suit) + (fromEnum pip)` to calculate the enumeration

Comment: @epsilonhalbe you probably meant `(maxBound :: Pip)` or `King` right? (for the first you need `deriving (..., Bounded)`

Comment: ya I always get it wrong - I should have consulted the docs for that

Comment: But suit and pip are in the Card, how can it work if suit and pip were separated   by maxBound? Should maxBound be Card {suit = Diamond, pip = King}

Comment: @Joe see my answer and play with it - basically the idea is how to enumerate say the pixels in an image - by doing the rows from top to bottom and the pixels in the rows left to right ((0,0) -> (1,0) -> ... (0,1) -> (1,1) -> ...) - if you want to go from (x,y) -> index you can calculate y*image-width+x (and back with division with remainder) - here it's the same only that `x = Pip` and `y = Suit`

Comment: @Carsten, but there are only 5 cards being enumerated, how about 52 cards ?  Err: ** Exception: toEnum{Suit}: tag (4) is outside of enumeration's range (0,3)

Comment: you are right - sorry gonna fix one moment

Comment: ok now you should get all - btw: I only picked 5 because all 52 (or the 49 I messed up before) seemed to be overkill - if you want to get all just try `[minBound .. maxBound] :: [Card]` - I double-checked and there are 52 there including the missing Kings ;)

Comment: @ Carsten Yes I got it Right now, Thanks1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here is how I would do it (basically the @epsilonhalbe's idea):

```
data Suit
   = Spade | Heart | Club | Diamond
   deriving (Eq, Ord, Enum, Show, Bounded)

data Pip
   = Ace | Two | Three | Four | Five | Six | Seven | Eight | Nine
   | Ten | Jack | Queen | King
   deriving (Eq, Ord, Enum, Show, Bounded)

data Card = Card
     { suit :: Suit
     , pip :: Pip
     } deriving (Eq,Ord, Show, Bounded)

instance Enum Card where
  toEnum i =
    let (d,m) = i `divMod` (fromEnum (maxBound :: Pip) + 1)
    in Card (toEnum d) (toEnum m)
  fromEnum (Card s p) = fromEnum s * (fromEnum (maxBound :: Pip) + 1) + fromEnum p
```

this gives you:

```
λ> take 5 $ [minBound .. maxBound] :: [Card]
[Card {suit = Spade, pip = Ace},Card {suit = Spade, pip = Two},Card {suit = Spade, pip = Three},Card {suit = Spade, pip = Four},Card {suit = Spade, pip = Five}]
```

---

PS: now you should get all - sorry I messed up the `maxBound` forgetting the one extra