# Generating a sublist from cycle in Haskell

Tags: haskell, cycle

Let's say I have a list of twelve musical notes (which have their own data type), and I want a function that returns a list of notes starting with a given note and looping around.

```
data Note = C | CsDb | D | DsEb | E | F | FsGb | G | GsAb | A | AsBb | B deriving (Read, Eq, Ord, Enum, Bounded)
getNotes :: Note -> [Note]
getNotes root = take 12 $ doSomething root $ cycle noteList
    where noteList :: [Note]
          noteList = [minBound..maxBound]
```

such that

```
ghci> getNotes E
[E, F, FsGb, G, GsAb, A, AsBb, B, C, CsDb, D, DsEb]
```

I can think of a few sloppy ways to do this, but it feels like there should be an obvious, very Haskellian way.  Any recommendations?

Comment: `doSomething = dropWhile . (/=)`

Comment: @DanielWagner, you nailed it.  If you want to make this comment an answer I'll check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The smallest change you can make that works is to use `dropWhile`:

```
getNotes :: Note -> [Note]
getNotes root = take 12 . dropWhile (/= root) . cycle $ [minBound .. maxBound]
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd just

```
getNotes root = [root .. maxBound] ++ init [minBound .. root]
```

but I can see how you prefer the cyclic approach. How about

```
getNotes root = map snd . take 12 $ [(0,root) .. ]
```

...sadly, that doesn't in fact work: it would need a `(Enum a, Enum b, Bounded b) => Enum (a,b)` instance, which for some reason isn't defined, at least not in the prelude.

Alternatively, you can use the index of `root`:

```
getNotes root = take 12 . drop (fromEnum root) $ cycle [minBound .. maxBound]
```

Comment: there was a question on that not long ago ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33785138/fromenum-toenum-instance/33786042#33786042 - maybe it's interesting - it's not hard to implement (the tuple version for `Enum`)

Comment: @Carsten: any idea why that instance isn't in `base`? Hm, I see it would require `Eq`. Still, might be a worthwhile proposal...

Comment: no clue - best guess: the way to enumerate might be up to debate - also note that I did not check the laws (so there might be some problem there)

Comment: @leftaroundabout `Enum` is a surprisingly tricky class. For example, there's nothing stopping you from defining `data X = A | B` with `instance Enum X where toEnum 3 = A; toEnum 7 = B` -- and this kind of thing (where there are "holes" in the enumeration) happens quite often when writing wrappers around C libraries with C enums.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the second idea of @leftaroundabout this is a working version - just in case you are curious and want to play with it:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

module Stackoverflow where

data Note = C | CsDb | D | DsEb | E | F | FsGb | G | GsAb | A | AsBb | B
          deriving (Show, Enum, Bounded)

instance (Enum a, Enum b, Bounded b) => Enum (a,b) where
  toEnum i =
    let (d,m) = i `divMod` (fromEnum (maxBound :: b) + 1)
    in (toEnum d, toEnum m)
  fromEnum (a, b) = fromEnum a * (fromEnum (maxBound :: b) + 1) + fromEnum b

getNotes :: Note -> [Note]
getNotes root = map snd . take 12 $ [(0,root) .. ]
```

example:

```
λ> getNotes E
[E,F,FsGb,G,GsAb,A,AsBb,B,C,CsDb,D,DsEb]
```

---

PS: the idea is extremely smart @leftaroundabout <- so guys make sure to give him lot's of upvotes ;)

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
getNotes :: Note -> [Note]
getNotes root = ys ++ xs where (xs,ys) = break (==root) [minBound..maxBound]
```

? This is more-or-less the same as @leftaroundabout's first suggestion, avoids the `init`, but incurs a number of equality comparisons :-)